# JQuery: How to apply this click function to all elements of the same class on the page?

Tags: php, jquery, click

My page consists of a list of records retrieved from a database and when you click on certain `span` elements it updates the database but at present this only works for the first record to be displayed.

(Basically changes a 0 to 1 and vice versa)

These are my two html elements on the page that are echoed out inside a loop:

```
Featured:<span class="featured-value">'.$featured.'</span>
Visible:<span class="visible-value">'.$visible.'</span>
```

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {           
    $('.featured-value').click(function() {
            var id = $('.id-value').text();
            var featured = $('.featured-value').text();
            $('.featured-value').fadeOut('slow');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data: "id="+id+"&featured="+featured,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.featured-value').html(data);
                    $('.featured-value').fadeIn('slow');        
                }
            });
        return false;
    });

    // same function for a different span
    $('.visible-value').click(function() {
        var id = $('.id-value').text();
        var visible = $('.visible-value').text();
        $('.visible-value').fadeOut('slow');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: "id="+id+"&visible="+visible,
            success: function(data) {
                $('.visible-value').html(data);
                $('.visible-value').fadeIn('slow');     
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

It was working fine with one using id attributes but now I'm using class the `fadeIn` part of the success query isn't working but I'm hoping the `.each` will fix this.

**UPDATE**
The full loop is as follows:

```
while ($event = $db->get_row($events, $type = 'MYSQL_ASSOC'))
{
    // open event class
    echo '<div class="event">';

    echo '<div class="id"><span class="row">Event ID:</span><span class="id-value"> '.$id.'</span></div>';

    echo '<div class="featured"><span class="row">Featured: </span><span class="featured-value">'.$featured.'</span></div>';
    echo '<div class="visible"><span class="row">Visible: </span><span class="visible-value">'.$visible.'</span></div>';

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cymen is right about the id selector causing you trouble. Also, I decided to refactor that for you. Might need some tweaks, but doesn't everything?

```
function postAndFade($node, post_key) {
    var id = $node.parents('.id').find('.id-value').text();
    var post_val = $node.text();
    $node.fadeOut('slow');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: "id="+id+"&"+post_key+"="+post_val,
        success: function(data) {
           $node.html(data);
           $node.fadeIn('slow');        
        }
    });
    return false;
}

$('.featured-value').click(function() { return postAndFade($(this), 'featured'); });

$('.visible-value').click(function() { return postAndFade($(this), 'visible'); });
```

Comment: thanks, I am just trying out your answer just now although there seems to be a closing bracket missing on the last two lines I think?

I appreciate the re-factoring but I'm just trying to figure out how to make it apply to my work because depending on what is clicked I need to supply that to the `process.php` script.

e.g. If `$('.featured-value')` is clicked it sends `data: "id="+id+"&featured="+featured,` but if it's `$('.visible-value')` it sends `data: "id="+id+"&visible="+visible,` so that my script knows which column in the table to change. Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. See if the updated code works for you.

Comment: thanks @lewsid, much appreciated. I thought that would work but the click functions don't seem to be doing anything so I can only assume it's the initial `var id = $node.parents().find().('.id-value').text();` selector that's not quite right.

Comment: Yea, the best I can do was make an educated guess. If you post code of where your buttons are in relation to the rest of your code, I can whip up the selector that should work.

Comment: that's very kind of you. I don't actually have buttons, I am simply clicking the 1 and 0 themselves (the `visible-value` and `featured-value` span elements) for the function to execute and update the database. I kind of lied, that's not the full loop, there is some other stuff but for readability I just kept in the stuff that directly relates to the question so I don't think that would affect anything or help to figure this one out.

Comment: tried it but still no fancy fading in and out :( I had it all inside a `document.ready(function{)` and tried removing that just incase but still the same. aaaaaaaaaaaaaaah. Very frustrating!

Comment: Fire up the javascript console - getting any errors? Also, pop a console.log($node) inside the ajax success function. What is its output?

Comment: yeah, sorry, I meant to say that there's no errors in firebug although now I know why, I didn't have the console enabled...... hmm it's complaining about `missing ;  postAndFade($node, post_key) { `

Comment: thanks! Only thing I'm getting now is `$this is not defined` :/ I had actually just noticed the same things you did with `function` missing and the extra `.` after parent aswell. Must be close to working now!!!!

Comment: turns out it was `$(this)` that was needed... thanks again for your help

Comment: Awesome, I updated the code snippet for others. Glad to help!

Comment: cool. thanks again for your help, hope anyone that discovers this finds it useful!

Answer (score 2):

The click function is getting the same id and value on each click because you've bound it to the class. Instead, you can take advantage of event.target assuming these values are on the item being clicked. If not, you need to use event.target and navigate to the items within the row.

```
$('.featured-value').click(function(event) {
        var $target = $(event.target);
        var id = $target.attr('id');
        var featured = $target.text();
        $target.fadeOut('slow');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: "id="+id+"&featured="+featured,
            success: function(data) {
                $target.html(data).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

So something like that but it  likely won't work as it needs to be customized to your HTML.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I will give it a try just now. I included two lines of html as these are the two elements I am targeting. I can post more if you would like?

Comment: Are the two HTML elements echoed out in the loop inside another element? I'll update my answer to show how I'd normally do that.